# Does a mithral rose change your weapon to silver, or add it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The *mithral rose* (*Mythic Adventures*) states that...

> When wearing the rose openly on his chest, the wearer treats all of his natural attacks, unarmed attacks, and weapon attacks as if they were made using silver weapons.

If you attack with a cold iron weapon, do you treat the attack as from a silver weapon, or from a cold iron **and** silver weapon?

I ask because I use *Path of War* strikes that inflict vulnerability to silver (causing the creature to take +50% additional damage from silver weapons, per their definition), but I'll mostly be using it against creatures that have DR/cold iron, and so I have a cold iron weapon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### An attack from a [cold iron](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/special-materials#TOC-Iron-Cold) weapon wielded by the wearer of a [*mithral rose*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-magic-items/other-magic-items) is a cold iron weapon that's also treated as a silver weapon

Such a weapon should overcome [DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction) X/cold iron and [DR](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Damage-Reduction) X/silver *and* affect creatures that are in some way vulnerable to cold iron, silver, or both, no matter the reason for that vulnerability.

The *mithral rose* (9,000 gp; 0 lbs.) says that "the wearer treats all of his natural attacks, unarmed attacks, and weapon attacks as if they were made using silver weapons." This statement is neither clarified nor qualified, but at its most basic the *rose* should permit the wearer's natural, unarmed, and weapon attacks to be treated as silver *in addition to*—not *instead of*—the attack's normal properties.

Lest a DM think it overpowered or unprecedented that an attack can be treated as both silver and whatever *actually* comprises the weapon, point the DM to other effects that do exactly the same thing (e.g. the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*heart of metal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heart-of-the-metal), the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*versatile weapon*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/versatile-weapon)).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the player whose GM says "Your attacks are treated as if made using silver weapons. Since a thing composed of silver is not also composed of cold iron, your weapons doesn't count as cold iron for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction."

Comment: @Metool I can't find a definition of **Weight** that makes **— lbs.** different from **0 lbs.** or **negligible lbs.** (I personally list things as *0 lbs.* (which isn't a thing) instead of *negligible lbs.* (also not a thing) or *— lbs.* (sort of a thing) because it's easier to deal with *0 lbs.* when computing encumbrance.)

Comment: Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Comment: Was tracking down my book. This answer doesn't cover my source of vulnerability, which uses the verbiage " a creature struck must succeed at a Will save (DC 12 + your initiation modifier) or become vulnerable to silver until the end of your next turn. Creatures with vulnerability to silver take 50% more damage from silver weapons." Good general answer, doesn't cover my specific case.

Comment: A number of maneuvers from the Mithral Current discipline in *Path of War: Expanded* such as Iron Wave, a 2nd-level strike.

Comment: @GuidingLight Is this your real question:  When a creature that wields a silver weapon employs the maneuver Iron Wave and successfully attacks a foe *and* that foe fails the saving throw against the Mithral Wave, does the Mithral Wave attack deal the foe extra 50% damage, or must the creature make *another* successful attack to possibly exploit the foe's vulnerability? (Not trying to be difficult; just seeing if we're communicating.)

Comment: No. Once Iron Wave or another similar maneuver has been used (one of the circumstances being assumed, the creature failed its save), does an attack from a creature (not necessarily the initiator) with a cold iron weapon and a *mithral rose* exploit the vulnerability and bypass DR/cold iron?

Answer (score 2):

> This seemingly delicate silver rose is rigid and nearly unbreakable. When wearing the rose openly on his chest, the wearer treats all of his natural attacks, unarmed attacks, and weapon attacks as if they were made using silver weapons. The wearer can expend one use of mythic power when making a melee attack against an enemy that possesses DR/silver to negate that DR for a number of rounds equal to the wearer's mythic tier.

When worn the Mithral Rose turns all of your attacks to silver attacks, based on the text. It also allows you to Negate an Enemy's Damage resistance so that other allies don't suffer damage penalties.

My apologies for not being clear. Since the purpose of the Mithral Rose is to Bypass the damage reduction of creatures weak to silver, it only makes sense that a cold iron weapon would still function normally as well. You would be able to bypass DR #/Mithral, or DR #/Cold Iron regularly if you were attacking using a Cold iron weapon.

The same case would apply if you were using an Adamantine weapon as well. It would just be treated as an Adamantine weapon with silver properties.